# ArrayList initial size doesn't work

Tags: java, arraylist, stack

I create a stack class with the name `StackOfBook`. I need 2 stacks so I create this on my main class:

```
StackOfBook stack1 = new StackOfBook();

while (true) {
    long number = sc.nextLong();
    if (number == -1) {
        break;
    }
    stack1.push(number);
}

StackOfBook stack2 = new StackOfBook(stack1.getTop());
```

This is my stack class:

```
private int top = 0;
private ArrayList<Long> arrBook;

public StackOfBook(){
    arrBook = new ArrayList<Long>();
}

public StackOfBook(int size){
    arrBook= new arrBook<Long>(size);
}

public int getTop() {
    return this.top;
}
```

I tried to initialize the `ArrayList` in the second stack without changing its top, but when I tried this the `ArrayList` in my stack2 doesn't initialize with `stack1.getTop()`. I have checked the variable size in the constructor and it has a value. Why is it wrong?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is the problem?

Comment: `arrBook= new arrBook<Long>(size);` Do you mean `new ArrayList<Long>(size)`?

Comment: you sure you're changing the value of top somewhere?

Comment: The problem is I think I can initialize the size of ArrayList. I have got the answer now. Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ArrayList` is backed by, as its name indicates, an array. Arrays are fixed-size; when the `ArrayList` gets near the array's capacity, it resizes it - it creates a new array, copies everything over, and ditches the old array.

When you initialize an `ArrayList` with a "size", that's actually its initial default capacity. It does *not* initialize anything into the array. The `ArrayList` is still empty after you create it; you still need to actually add values to the `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

The int argument to the ArrayList(n) constructor is merely used to set an initial capacity for the list. Its size is still zero until you put something in it. The initial capacity is used internally so that the list does not have to reallocate more space until you put more than n items in it.